# Is it possible to override injected Request from a Laravel Package?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, package, ioc-container

I'm building a custom package in Laravel that has a resource Controller. For this example the resource is an `Organization`  In this Controller the basic `index`, `show`, `store` etc actions are defined.

This is my `store` method in the controller:

```php
     /**
     * Store a newly created Organization in storage.
     *
     * @param  OrganizationStoreRequest  $request
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function store($request): JsonResponse
    {
        $newOrganization = new Organization($request->all());

        if ($newOrganization->save()) {
            return response()->json($newOrganization, 201);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'message' => trans('organilations::organisation.store.error')
        ], 500);
    }
```

My `OrganzationStoreRequest` is pretty basic for now:

```php
class OrganizationStoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

The store method can be called on a API When the package is being used in a Laravel application. My problem here is that I want to give the users of my package the ability to override my `OrganizationStoreRequest` with there own requests, as they might have to use different authorize or validation methods.

I've tried building a middleware and Binding my own instance to the `OrganizationStoreRequests` but I'm not getting the results I want.

Is there anyway for the user of the package to be able to override the `OrganizationStoreRequets` in the controller of my package ?

Comment: It's a little ugly, but what about a config file identifying the Request::class they want to use and then a custom binding https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/container#binding-interfaces-to-implementations

Answer (score 2):

With the help of fellow developers on Larachat we've come to the following (easy) solution.

When creating an own request we can bind an instance of it to the IoC Container. For example, creating the `OrganizationOverrideRule` and extending the original:

```php
class OrganizationOverrideRules extends OrganizationStoreRequest
{    
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'website' => 'required',
            'tradename' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

Then in the `AppServiceProvider` you can bind the new instance like so:

```php
App::bind(
    OrganizationStoreRequest::class,
    OrganizationOverrideRules::class
);
```

Then the `OrganizationOverrideRules` will be used for validation and authorization.

Comment: This is perfect!

Simple, clever and concise. Exactly what I needed. Thank you for sending me on the right path!